# CATransition working wrong on orientation change before dismissing a NavigationViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Here is my code used to present a navigationViewController :

```
-(IBAction)showFilterView:(id)sender {

    FilterViewController *vc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FilterViewController"];
    UINavigationController *nvc=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];


    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.35;
    transition.timingFunction =
    [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;

    UIView *containerView = self.view.window;
    [containerView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
    [self.tabBarController presentViewController:nvc animated:NO completion:nil];

}
```

And here is my code to dismiss

```
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender {


    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.35;
    transition.timingFunction =
    [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
    UIView *containerView = self.view.window;
    [containerView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
    [[self.navigationController presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Situation 1 --- Working well in landscape mode

Situation 2 --- Working well in portrait mode

Situation 3 --- Presenting in a portrait mode and dismissing in landscape mode not working properly(extra animation before displaying correct view)

Situation 4 ---Presenting in a landscape mode and dismissing in portrait mode not working properly(extra animation before displaying correct view)

Comment: Does it help https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html

Comment: I tested your code on iPad-project and it works fine with one animation, except that I tested with presenting from self not from a tabBarController:  `[self  presentViewController:nvc animated:NO completion:nil]`

Comment: In UIView *containerView = self.view.window you are assigning the whole window (UIWindow*) to a UIView *. Shouldn't you be animating the view layer, not the window?

Answer (score 0):

The UIWindow layer has weird rotation properties and any animations you perform aren't guaranteed to correctly detect orientation (and vary with different iOS versions). The easiest way to do what you're trying to is with a custom presentation animation. [This is a good writeup](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/) of how to do it.